# Should I completely rebuild my server due to Heartbleed?

Tags: centos, security, ssl, openssl, heartbleed

I have a CentOS 6.5 VPS server...

```
$ uname -a 
Linux mary 3.14.4-x86_64-linode40 #1 SMP Tue May 13 12:25:05 EDT 2014 \
    x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When the news about the Heartbleed vulnerability came out, I shut it down.

It was running Apache, MySQL, and a Ruby on Rails app. It did use OpenSSL.

I'm pretty sure it was running with vulnerable versions of OpenSSL for some time.

I booted it up again today and ran `yum -y update`.

I now seem to have the patched version of OpenSSL...

```
$ openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
built on: Tue Apr  8 02:39:29 UTC 2014
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DPURIFY -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  rdrand dynamic
```

I think I have two options...

1. Revoke and reissue my SSL certificate for the domain and keep using the machine.
2. Assume the machine is compromised and delete it, create a whole new VPS, install everything.

Rebuilding the entire system is a 1-2 day job.

Is it necessary or overkill?

Comment: It all comes down to the importance of the data(and its integrity) and the service the VPS is performing. May i suggest you rebuild the machine while making sure and documenting a faster way to rebuild your system. There is always room for optimizations.

Comment: I don't see any reason to rebuild the machine. Unless of course it was compromised through some _other_ means. Heartbleed doesn't necessarily give anyone access to your server.